# How to delete a specific row in sqlite databse in android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have used a separate class for creation of db. In that I have written the delete function like this

```
public void name_delete(String name){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_NAME + "=" + name, null);
//KEY_NAME is a column name
}
```

In main class I called this function

```
db.name_delete(""+all_names.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

**all_names.getSelectedItem().toString()** is a spinner selected item. To delete the particular row with the name selected in spinner. Help me how to write the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_NAME + "=?", new String[]{name});
```

Also

```
db.name_delete(all_names.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Comment: delete function working perfectly.I have 5 names,each name have one id from 1 to 5.when delete the 4th name the row id will be 1,2,3,5.How to arrange 1,2,3,4.(is tit possible)

Comment: you can do an update and set the id to 4 where id=5, what is this id? is it the table primary key?

Answer (score 2):

```
public void name_delete(String name){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_NAME +"=?", new String[]{name});
}
```

USE this

Comment: delete function working perfectly.I have 5 names,each name have one id from 1 to 5.when delete the 4th name the row id will be 1,2,3,5.How to arrange 1,2,3,4.